# Kendo Multiselect how to set readonly attribute everywhere?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have over 30+ Kendo UI Multiselect elements in my application, some of which are declared dynamically and some statically (in HTML). I want to disable text input in the kendo input field, so I do

```
$(".k-input").attr('readOnly', true);
```

for each Kendo multiselect, but this is proving to be quite painful. How do I set the readonly parameter to true for all the Kendo multiselect elements? Is there any way I can do this "globally"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through the different multiselect using and then invoking `readonly` method:

```
$.each($("[data-role='multiselect']"), function(idx, elem) { 
    $(elem).data("kendoMultiSelect").readonly(true);
});
```

Check it here: http://dojo.telerik.com/@OnaBai/ijEzE